# Auto-saving in VB.NET after inactivity

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm at a loss on the best way to accomplish this. I am running a VB.NET web application that will automatically redirect to a main index page after approx 20 minutes of inactivity. I would like to do an "autosave" to our SQL Server before this redirect. But I can't figure out a way to trigger this save function before the redirect occurs. What would be the best solution for this, given that I need to keep my current code as is?

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    'Javascript to reload page after 20 mintues of inactivity


    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "script", "<script language='javascript'> setTimeout(function(){ window.location = 'http://www.toxicology.org/ai/meet/master/adminMtgsDept.aspx'; }, 1200000); </script>")
```

Comment: You're basically telling the browser to redirect the user.  The server side code has no knowledge of this happening so you cannot make this work with the code as is.

Comment: What SessionState option are you using ? If it's InProc (i.e. in memory), then you can call code from `Session_End` in global.asax to do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is AJAX an option? You can use the AJAX control toolkit timer control to trigger a server-side method that saves your data. The timer should reset after every postback, so if someone walks away it should fire after your interval.

Comment: I tried this after your suggestion, and I can get the timer to fire after a specified time, but this only works if the user does not interact with form. My first page is a gridview that user can select a row to edit. If they don't click on a row to edit, then the timer functions. But if they do click on a row to edit, the timer never functions. Thoughts? I've never used this timer before, so excuse my ignorance.

Comment: You should be able to reset and restart the timer after a postback. Here's the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398865%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Tim, it was my silly mistake. I had the timer inside my first page panel. I took it out of my page panels (i have a 1st,2nd, and 3rd page panels) and now it is behaving how I want. Thanks so much for the helpful suggestion!

Comment: Glad I could help! I've only had to implement this once but it can be a life saver long as your user has Javascript enabled.